# Column swapping possible in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to bootstrap. Suppose I create a 3 column view using bootstrap like: 
col1   col2   col3

Can I convert this layout as follows on mobile view?

col2  col1  col3

Is this possible?
Reason: In desktop view, col 1 will have advertisement, col2 will have contents and col 3 will have advertisement board. I want content to be above all advertisements only in mobile view.

Comment: so, what have you already tried? do you have any markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check my link [**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/PzVmEm)

Column ordering is the inbulit feature of bootstrap framework. For more information visit [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow... thats great .. I was un-aware of this feature. Thanks a lot. Can you please link me up to some tutorial where I can learn bootsrap in depth as a beginner?

Comment: The Best way to learn Bootstrap is To Learn From Their Official Website
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/